# result of pycharm optimize imports

Tags: python, import, pycharm, pep8

I used "code/optimize imports" in Pycharm and it resulted in this

```
import logging
import os
import re
import subprocess
from getpass import getpass
from pathlib import Path

import requests
import sys
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

why is it in this order? why is there a blank line?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it uses `isort` (https://pypi.org/project/isort/):

1. `import` is before `from x import y`
2. Than the imports are sorted alphabetically.
3. And lastly the imports are grouped by the type of the import. The blank line between your imports is the separator between `Python Standard Library` imports and `Third Party` imports.

   > isort parses specified files for global level import lines (imports
   > outside of try / except blocks, functions, etc..) and puts them all at
   > the top of the file grouped together by the type of import:
   >
   > - Future
   > - Python Standard Library
   > - Third Party
   > - Current Python Project
   > - Explicitly Local (. before import, as in: from . import x)
   > - Custom Separate Sections (Defined by forced_separate list in configuration file)
   > - Custom Sections (Defined by sections list in configuration file)
   >
   > Inside of each section the imports are sorted alphabetically. isort
   > automatically removes duplicate python imports, and wraps long from
   > imports to the specified line length (defaults to 79).

#### Edit:

Group imports by type is recommended also in PEP8 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)

Comment: time and sys are third party modules?

Comment: Nope, sorry I haven't seen that. That is really strange because also pytcharm documentations says:

"Besides cleaning the code from the unused imports, PyCharm formats the existing import statements according to the Style Guide for Python Code. In doing so, PyCharm splits import statements into separate lines, and sorts them into groups (refer to the Imports section for details). "
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html#optimize-imports-in-project

Comment: I also find this very confusing, PyCharm always puts `import sys` at the bottom group.